# XHR Post for saving document.body JS

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

i need to post document.body.innerHTML to my domain's proxy. There is working PM2 and before it I used GET and it looked like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://domain.ru/pmproxy?info='+document.body.innerHTML+'&location='+document.location+1);
xhr.send();
```

Now, because there is a limit of letters I need to us POST. How can I turn this into POST?

Comment: By replacing `'GET'` with `'POST'`. Also, it’s probably a good idea to `encodeURIComponent` your innerHTML before you get an error due to it containing a special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the receiving server method accepts post and if you want to send data in xhr post you can do like this

`xhr.send("info='+document.body.innerHTML+'&location='+document.location+1")`

or if a server accepts a json object then you can use `xhr.send(document.getElementById('#form).serialize());`

Answer (score -1):

You should convert it to this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://domain.ru/pmproxy');
xhr.send('info='+document.body.innerHTML+'&location='+document.location+1);
```

Also, I suggest you clean both parameters, so you can avoid problems in the future:

```
xhr.send('info='+encodeURIComponent(document.body.innerHTML)+'&location='+encodeURIComponent(document.location+1));
```

Furthermore, I don't really know why you're using document.location+1, but you can use document.location.href and save the +1 so your code looks cleaner:

```
xhr.send('info='+encodeURIComponent(document.body.innerHTML)+'&location='+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href));
```